# editing attached source file in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse IDE and want to edit the attached source file of the jar file. For doing this i downloaded the src.zip and attached the file, but it is opening as a .class though I am able to read the file (which is a .class file) but i also want to edit the file.

Why I am not allowed to edit it? how to open an attached file with .java extension not .class extension.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. In order to edit the source, you have to unpack the JAR and create an eclipse project, from which you can then create a JAR with the modified code.

Comment: Oh that means attaching a source doesn't mean we actually attached source code and we are allowed to change the code.moreover it is not possible to make changes in the attached source code.

Comment: @Anupam: yes, attaching source is only intended to help understanding code by allowing you to easily look at the source of the library classes you use.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to link it... Source files are not tied to compiled classes in jar, so if you edit it, nothing will happen to the jar file

You have to create a separate project in Eclipse, and rebuild the jar with your modifications

Comment: I am not even able to edit it .It is opening only in .class file I want to open it as .java file

Comment: why eclipse is opening the code as .class type when actually i have attached a .java file

Comment: I think we've all understood you wanted to modify the source file. But you just want to view it as a java source, do you ? Please use an other term than `edit` which in computing context means `modify`

Comment: No I actually want to edit/modify the attached .java file for a jar file and I hope Michael Borgwardt understood my question and answered it correctly

Answer (score 0):

.class files are not readable by human being unless you decompile it. Many decompilers exist. Carefull about what you are allowed to do and what you aren't, though...

Usually, .java aren't in .jar.

Comment: that is what my doubt is.... When I am attaching a source for a jar then the attached source is being shown by the ID with .class type... why not .java file ...when actually i have attached a .java file

Comment: I don't think you did. If you use Eclipse, even that you don't see what happens, you did add .class files. Sorry.